# cannot import name 'awesome_cossim_topn' from 'sparse_dot_topn' (unknown location)

Tags: cosine-similarity

after installing the `sparse_dot_topn` package I received the error message:

```
from sparse_dot_topn import awesome_cossim_topn
```

> ImportError: cannot import name 'awesome_cossim_topn' from 'sparse_dot_topn' (unknown location)